# C++ Why bitwise operator ~ on uint64_t and uint8_t return different types?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, undefined-behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    uint64_t a = 3;
    if (uint64_t(~a) == (~a))
        cout << "right" << endl;//right
    else
        cout << "wrong" << endl;
    cout << sizeof(~a) << endl;//8

    uint8_t b = 3;
    if (uint8_t(~b) == (~b))
        cout << "right" << endl;
    else
        cout << "wrong" << endl;//wrong
    cout << sizeof(~b) << endl;//4
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

~uint8_t returns int value,but ~uint64_t returns uint64_t .

Is this undefined behaviour ?

Comment: You need to look up integer promotion rules.

Comment: this is defined behaviour, all arithmetic operators (including `~`) promote operands to `int` if they are narrower type than `int`. It comes from the early days of C when arithmetic was done in registers and they didnt want to make it more complicated by simulating arithmetic on smaller units than the register.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posting from [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

> The result of `operator~` is the bitwise NOT (one's complement) value
>   of the argument (**after promotion**).

[Integral promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) is applied to `char`, `short int` etc (types narrower than `int`) and the result needs to be casted to destination type if destination is not `int`.

This is the reason for `sizeof(~b) == sizeof(int)` in your case.